# How can i read csv file datas from csv files in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

Im new on the ruby on rails
How can i read datas from csv files?
I have a csv file, and it has datas like name surname etc.

Here, there is a name surname variables. I need to read from csv files. How can i do it?

my codes now like this:

```
require 'csv'

table = CSV.parse(File.read("csv files/department.csv"), headers: true)

class Person
    @name
    @surname
    @role
    @department
    def printPersonFullname(name, surname)
        @name = name
        @surname = surname
        puts ("#{@name} #{@surname}")
    end
end
```

here csv file image:

[image]

By the way, when i print, console print this:
`D:\Ruby27-x64\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- csv.rb (LoadError`)

Comment: Exactly where is located your code for the csv processing? and how is it executed?

Comment: They are in lib/tasks/csv files. It is csv file, there are rows like name,surname etc. ,and there are columns which has data like Efe Şahin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes a working example of reading CSV, instantiating `Person` object and printing.

```rb
# following the directory tree:
#   ./
#   ./tasks/main.rb
#   ./csv/department.csv
#
# csv file example
#
# name,surname,department
# John,Doe,IT
# Bill,Doe,IT
#
# running this code:
#   ruby tasks/main.rb
require 'csv'

class Person
  def initialize(name, surname, department)
    @name = name
    @surname = surname
    @department = department
  end

  def print_full_name
    puts "#{@name} #{@surname}"
  end
end

### main
filepath = "#{__dir__}/../csv/department.csv"
CSV.foreach(filepath, headers: true) do |row|
  person = Person.new(
    row["name"],
    row["surname"],
    row["department"]
  )

  person.print_full_name
end
```

Your code in the question wasn't written in ruby way. I recommend you to read this [ruby styleguide](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide) to follow some practices on our community